# Does libpcap watch sent packets?

Tags: c++, c, packet, libpcap

Does pcap_next display packets that were sent?

For example:
If I ping google.com while libpcap is listening for packets, then run pcap_next twice, will both of the returned values be a packet, or will one of them be null?

**Edit:**
Yes it does.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, it does.

*And here is some extra text to satisfy the rules.*